# JSSC - Adding SerialPortEventListener to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, rfid, jssc

I need some help on how EventListeners work in java. I'll be honest, the only Listener I know how to use is ActionListeners so forgive me for not knowing how. To start with, I would like to put on some reference.

Im working on an RFID Scanner Desktop App on java and EPOCH gave me this:
[JSSC](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-simple-serial-connector/wikis/jSSC_examples.wiki)

The JSSC was able to provide me with the tools that I need to read my RFID but this time, I'm having issued on Implementing it on my application.

Here is my current Code:

First, Imports

```
import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortEvent;
import jssc.SerialPortEventListener;
import jssc.SerialPortException;
```

Now for the class:

```
class SerialPortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {
        SerialPort serialPort;
        @Override
        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
            if(event.isRXCHAR()){//If data is available
                if(event.getEventValue() == 10){//Check bytes count in the input buffer
                    //Read data, if 10 bytes available 
                    try {
                        byte buffer[] = serialPort.readBytes(10);
                    }
                    catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex);
                    }
                }
            }else if(event.isCTS()){//If CTS line has changed state
                if(event.getEventValue() == 1){//If line is ON
                    System.out.println("CTS - ON");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("CTS - OFF");
                }
            }else if(event.isDSR()){///If DSR line has changed state
                if(event.getEventValue() == 1){//If line is ON
                    System.out.println("DSR - ON");
                }else {
                    System.out.println("DSR - OFF");
                }
            }
        }
    }

public class TestRF extends javax.swing.JFrame implements SerialPortEventListener{
    SerialPort serialPort;

    public TestRF() {
        initComponents();
        setSerialPort();

    }

    public void setSerialPort(){
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM7");
        try {
            serialPort.openPort();//Open serial port
            serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);//Set params.
            byte[] buffer = serialPort.readBytes(10);//Read 10 bytes from serial port
            //serialPort.closePort();//Close serial port
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);//Add SerialPortEventListener
        }
        catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

and lastly, the abstract method.. (I dont know what this does to be honest and im picking up books right now.)

```
@Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent spe) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
```

to put things simple. I need to get my RFID to read and pass that value anywhere in my project. I even thought of trying to extend my JFrame classes to a class file but so far, no luck.
tutorials anyone?

Comment: You want to get rid of `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");`, otherwise you might have some issues you aren't expecting.  You need to use an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) of some kind between your `SerialPortReader` and `TestRF` classes. Beware though, Swing is single threaded and not thread safe, so you need to make sure you're not blocking the EDT, but also, that any updates you make to the UI are done from within the context of the EDT.

Comment: Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the answers MadProgrammer, this is quite interesting since I needed to learn the threading but right now I just need this one to work. I've noticed why you recommended me with these links. I got the application working with no errors but with a catch. I need to swipe the ID first before the actual jFrame appears! well thats just wrong. Got any temporary solutions for the problem? In 5 hours this program is gonna be checked by my instructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 threads. 1st thread read data from serial port (RFID) while 2nd thread handles task specific to application. Also consider using serial communication manager library for serial port communication in java.

Please share RFID hardware details so that we can think best application design to use it.